# Escape all commas in line except first and last

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, csv, notepad++

I have a CSV file which I'm trying to import to a SQL Server table. The file contains lines of 3 columns each, separated by a comma. The only problem is that some of the data in the second column contains an arbitrary number of commas. For example:

```
1281,I enjoy hunting, fishing, and boating,smith317
```

I would like to escape all occurrences of commas in each line except the first and the last, such that the result of this line would be:

```
1281,I enjoy hunting\, fishing\, and boating,smith317
```

I know I will need some type of regular expression to accomplish this task, but my knowledge of regular expressions is very limited. Currently, I'm trying to use Notepad++ find/replace with regex, but I am open to other ideas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, could be a manual stuff. Do this:

1. Normal find all the `,` and replace it with `\,`. Escape everything.
2. Regex find `^(.*)(\\,)` and replace it with `$1,`.
3. Regex find `(\\,)(.*)$` and replace it with `,$2`.

Worked for me in Sublime Text 2.